# How to get jsp data and displayed in a variable of a javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

I have a javascript table which will add rows dynamically

[image]

The code is as follows

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
                <script language="javascript">
                    // Add row to the HTML table


                    function addRow() {    
                        var table = document.getElementById('my_table'); //html table
                        var rowCount = table.rows.length; //no. of rows in table
                        var columnCount =  table.rows[0].cells.length; //no. of columns in table          
                        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount); //insert a row            

                        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0); //create a new cell           
                        var element1 = document.createElement("input"); //create a new element           
                        element1.type = "checkbox"; //set the element type 
                        element1.setAttribute('id', 'newCheckbox'); //set the id attribute   
                        element1.setAttribute('checked',true); //set checkbox by default checked  
                        cell1.appendChild(element1); //append element to cell

                        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);            
                        var element2 = document.createElement("input");            
                        element2.type = "text"; 
                        element2.setAttribute('id', 'newInput'); //set the id attribute
                        element2.setAttribute('name', 'sl'+rowCount);
                        element2.setAttribute('style', 'width: 50px');
                        cell2.appendChild(element2);      

                        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);            
                        var element3 = document.createElement("input");            
                        element3.type = "textarea"; 
                        element3.setAttribute('rows', '4');
                        element3.setAttribute('cols','40');
                        element3.setAttribute('id', 'newInput'); //set the id attribute
                        element3.setAttribute('name', 'discription'+rowCount);
                        cell3.appendChild(element3);         

                        var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);            
                        var element4 = document.createElement("input");            
                        element4.type = "text"; 
                        element4.setAttribute('id', 'newInput'); //set the id attribute
                        element4.setAttribute('name', 'quantity'+rowCount);
                        cell4.appendChild(element4);


                        var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);            
                        var element5 = document.createElement("input");            
                        element5.type = "text"; 
                        element5.setAttribute('id', 'newInput'); //set the id attribute
                        element5.setAttribute('name', 'price'+rowCount);
                        cell5.appendChild(element5);



                        var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);            
                        var element6 = document.createElement("input");            
                        element6.type = "text"; 
                        element6.setAttribute('id', 'newInput'); //set the id attribute
                        element6.setAttribute('name', 'CST'+rowCount);
                        element6.setAttribute('style', 'width: 50px');
                        cell6.appendChild(element6);


                        var cell7 = row.insertCell(6);
                        var element7 = false;

                        $.ajax({
                            type: "GET",
                            url: '/SalesPropeller/Admin/Sales/goal.jsp',
                            async: false,
                            success: function(data) {
                                 element7 = true;
                            },
                            error: function() {
                                alert("Your error");
                            },

                        });

                       element7.setAttribute('id', 'vat5'); //set the id attribute 
                       element7.setAttribute('name','tax'+rowCount);
                       element7.setAttribute('value','vat5');

                       cell7.appendChild(element7);
}
```

When i am clicking on "Addrow" button then rows are adding but in the last cell which is "Vat5.5" i need to get the data from another jsp page,so i am using to call the jsp using ajax and display the data, but after writing the ajax code it is not able to display the data.

goal.jsp

```
<body>
 <div id="welcomeDiv"> WELCOME</div>
</body>
```

This image is for whether i have path correctly or not.

[image]

So my question is how to display the data in the "Vat5.5" cell.I dont know whether i am doing wrong in the ajax call i guess.Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**

If `goal.jsp` is outputting the data (WELCOME), It should be

```
String data = "WELCOME";
out.print(data);
```

and in JavaScript,

```
// define a variable outside AJAX call
var jspData;
```

and in success function

```
success: function (data){
    jspData = data;   //response
    element7 = true;
}
```

**BEFORE EDIT**

supposing your data is a String, get your JSP data somehow and save in a String

```
String jspData;   // contains your jsp data

// In JSP(HTML)
<input id="jsp-data" type="hidden" value="<%=jspData%>" />

// In JavaScript
var data = document.getElementById('jsp-data').value;
```

now, you can use that `data` in JavaScript.